# How to understand "we are to considering"

Tags: american-english

I sent a question to recruiter asking if they are considering candidates from Europe (or from US only). I received such answer (excerpt):  "...At the moment, we are to considering candidates based outside the U.S..."

It feels like something is missing between "we" and "are". Or everything is ok, and they are considering candidates outside US?

Thanks!

Comment: Understand it as a typo :)

Comment: so how it would sound without typo?

Comment: @Armen That's what I thought it is, but if you google "to be to doing" (or other gerunds) you get a lot of hits. The chances all are a typo are slim (one of the first hits is from the BBC). Maybe it's some construction I'm unaware of?

Comment: While I’m sure the intention was “not considering” the sentence as written could be considered grammatical in the case that they are articulating which step they’ve gotten to in a multi-step plan. For instance 1. Consider only candidates in the U. S.  2. Consider candidates outside the U. S. 3. Consider replacement with a robot.  Now, one might be able to say we are to step 2 in the plan.-  I.e., we are to considering candidates outside the U.S.  *ok, maybe a bit of a stretch* ;-)

Answer (score 3):

The sentence is incorrect, and it's either a grammatical mistake that "to" is not supposed to be there or a typo for "not."  Unfortunately, these are opposite conclusions, and a bit of context would be helpful.

I would strongly guess it's the former, because putting "to" before the verb is the infinitive form and while "to" doesn't go before the gerund, that's an easily understandable mistake, especially if English is not the recruiter's native language.  If other parts of the message contain information about how to apply, that is further evidence supporting this interpretation.

You could reply with something like "Great!  I will get my application in soon" to communicate what your understanding was (assuming you do intend to apply soon) and if "not" was intended the recruiter should correct you.

Answer (score 1):

The sentence:

> At the moment, we are to considering candidates based outside the U.S.

is not correct.

It may have meant to be:

> At the moment, we are to consider candidates based outside the U.S.

or

> At the moment, we are considering candidates based outside the U.S.

or

> At the moment, we are to be considering candidates based outside the U.S.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is this:

...At the moment, we are to considering candidates based outside the U.S..."

Should have been written as

...At the moment, we are **too** considering candidates based outside the U.S..."

Both of which are incorrect, however, the Correct Interpretation of the statement is:

**They are also considering candidates that reside outside of the United States of America.**